# Ошибка 500 на Django сайте

Tags: django

Доброго времени суток!

Есть сайт на джанго (версия 1.3, знаю, что старая, сайт был сделан давно и не мною). Так вот, все работало прекрасно, но тут стала задача добавить раздел (app), на основе одного app он был создан, с сохранением уникальности имен. Затем в `setting.py` в INSTALLED_APPS он был добавлен. Следующим шагом была генерация кода sql на основе описанных моделей в файле model.py: `python ./manage.py sql app_name`, ну а потом `python ./manage.py syncdb`.

Сначала вылезала Undefined Error, поковырялся в логах, вроде как из-за повторения имен возникала ошибка, исправил все, в логах теперь чисто, сайт не пашет. Попробовал удалить таблицы, связанные с новым приложением -безрезультатно. При запуске fcgi-файла выдает следующее:

```
> WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
> WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
> WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
> WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
> /home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py:80:
> DeprecationWarning: A Field class whose get_db_prep_value method
> hasn't been updated to take `connection` and `prepared` arguments.  
> new_class = super(SubfieldBase, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
> /home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pages/http.py:72:
> DeprecationWarning: auto_render decorator is a deprecated.  
> warnings.warn(DeprecationWarning("auto_render decorator is a
> deprecated."))
> /home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/mptt/models.py:305:
> DeprecationWarning: Implicit manager Category.tree will be removed in
> django-mptt 0.6.  Explicitly define a TreeManager() on your model to
> remove this warning.   DeprecationWarning Status: 500 INTERNAL SERVER
> ERROR Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie Content-Type: text/html;
> charset=utf-8 Content-Language: ru-ru
```

Гуглил, копался в папках библиотек, результатов нет, дальше без понятия, что делать, жду советов!

---

Запустил DEBUG, вот что выдало:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://agatauto-quadro.ru/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
['admin_tools',
 'admin_tools.theming',
 'admin_tools.menu',
 'admin_tools.dashboard',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.comments',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'mptt',
 'tagging',
 'filebrowser',
 'tinymce',
 'smart_selects',
 'pages',
 'zinnia',
 'quadriko',
 'snowko',
 'moto',
 'probeg',
 'begovel',
 'debug_toolbar']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  178.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/dj/aquadro/apps/ext/debug_toolbar/toolbar/loader.py" in render_toolbar
  95.         return render_to_string('debug_toolbar/base.html', context)
File "/home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  183.         return t.render(Context(dictionary))
File "/home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  123.             return self._render(context)
File "/home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  60.     return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_node
  757.         return node.render(context)
File "/home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  227.                 nodelist.append(node.render(context))
File "/home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  311.             return self.nodelist_true.render(context)
File "/home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_node
  757.         return node.render(context)
File "/home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  792.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
File "/home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  510.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)
File "/home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  653.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "/home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  698.                             current = current()
File "/home/virtwww/w_aquadro_963190fa/dj/aquadro/apps/ext/debug_toolbar/panels/sql.py" in content
  197.                     stacktrace.append(u'<span class="path">{0}/</span><span class="file">{1}</span> in <span class="func">{3}</span>(<span class="lineno">{2}</span>)\n  <span class="code">{4}</span>'.format(*params))

Exception Type: IndexError at /
Exception Value: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Если убрать debug_toolbar приложение - сайт работает?

Comment: Похоже, что новый debug_toolbar не поддерживает старую джангу. На сайте документации по нему есть таблица совместимости, проверьте